# Display laravel DB::select array in blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm doing a query in laravel with DB::select, I can't do this query via Eloquent, that returns a collection and the output works like {{bla->bla}}, but I need to push the entire query.

Now, my question is, how can I display the query results in blade?
How can I pass it to my view?

here is the dd of the array:
[dd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXFWL.jpg)

here is the start of my query:

```
$orderz = DB::select('SELECT * FROM orde ...........
```

So, to pass it in blade, what I need to do (@foreach, [arrayindex]? 
Convert to collection? Treat the array in a different manner?
Thank you :)
I searched a lot, but no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, pass this data to a view:

```
return view('some.view', ['orders' => $orders]);
```

Then iterate over it in the view:

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
    {{ $order->name }}
@endforeach
```

Also, you absolutely can and should use Eloquent in this situation.

Comment: I did a mistake in passing values to the view, i needed to pass some other vars and I messed it up.
By the way it works, sorry, and many thanks.
I was trying to convert to collection, print in strange manners, doing foreach inside controllers...
I think that the [] did the trick. Thank you :)